# Site's JavaScript is not working which is loaded inside the Angular iFrame with custom headers

Tags: angular, iframe, sanitization

It is required to load a site inside an iFrame in Angular 8.
The site has several JavaScripts.
To load that site we have to send `Authorization` header with the request.
I could simply load a javascript site with the approach mentioned in the following blog https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iframe-src?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html but with this approach, I cannot send authorization headers. So, I tried following StackOverflow answer [Angular 2 - Inject custom headers on iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763076/angular-2-inject-custom-headers-on-iframe). With that approach, I could successfully send the custom headers and load the site but loaded site's javascript is not working since we have to `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl`. The issue is the return type of `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl()` (`SafeResourceUrl`) cannot be pass to `get()` since it requires a `string`. How I can overcome this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could overcome the issue by using the `sandbox` element for the `<iFrame>` as follows.

```
<iframe #iframe width="100%" height="400px" sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation"></iframe>
```

I had to allow the above set of permission for the iFrame.

Comment: hi even I am stuck in this do you have a stackblitz sample on this?

Comment: @Ragav sorry, I don't have at the moment